# How to correctly garbage collect when using a NIF

Tags: erlang, ffi

I would have thought that if I all I do is 1) load a NIF library, 2)execute my new/0 method, 3) free everything via F(), and then 4) erlang:garbage:collect() that I would be back to where I started from with respect to memory. In fact, I am leaking memory. Clearly, my code is the most likely suspect.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct Node
{
  int Key;
  ERL_NIF_TERM TermPtr;
  struct Node *Next;
} Node;
```

My on-load opens up the resource

```
int on_load(ErlNifEnv* env, void** priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info)
{
    ErlNifResourceFlags flags = (ErlNifResourceFlags)(ERL_NIF_RT_CREATE | ERL_NIF_RT_TAKEOVER);
    NODE_RESOURCE = enif_open_resource_type(env,  "linkedlist_nif", 
                       "node_resource",
                       &node_dtor,
                       flags,
                       0);
}
```

new/0 gets mapped to this NIF:

```
static ERL_NIF_TERM new_nif(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
 ERL_NIF_TERM term;
  Node *Head =  (Node *)enif_alloc_resource(NODE_RESOURCE,sizeof(Node));

  Head->Next = 0;
  term = enif_make_resource(env, Head);
  enif_release_resource(Head);

  return enif_make_tuple2(env, enif_make_atom_len(env, "ok", 2), term);
}
```

and the destruct-or for the resource is as follows:

```
static void node_dtor(ErlNifEnv* env, void* arg)
{
    Node* handle = (Node*)arg;

    enif_release_resource(handle);
    handle = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in the shell you create a value with `A = your_nif:new().` then you free the value with `f().` then you `erlang:garbage_collect().` and you expect that your memory usage will be the same(ish) as before you started?

This likely won't happen as the shell keeps a history of the results of previous executions. This will keep references to the term alive throughout the `f().` and `garbage_collect().` and so you won't see the memory behaviour you expect.

You could do something like:

```
Before = erlang:memory().
Pid = spawn( fun () ->
  A = your_nif:new(),
  receive
    cleanup -> ok
  end
 end).
timer:sleep(timer:seconds(1)). % Wait for pid to spawn and allocate term.
During = erlang:memory().
Pid ! cleanup.
After = erlang:memory().

lists:zipwith3(fun ({K, B}, {K, D}, {K, A}) -> 
                 {K, _Values = {B, D, A}, {_Leaked = A - B, _Used = D - B}} end,
               Before, During, After).
```

This should show you some approximation of memory used during the test (not strictly accurate, but if the `your_nif:new()` term is big enough it'll eclipse other memory allocation), and leaked afterwards.

Comment: Far simpler approach how to avoid store value in history: `A = your_nif:new(), ok.`